# Brightness of view: Android

Tags: android

Is it possible to decrease the brightness of all views and keep brightness of one view as it was ? Like it happens when progress dialog appears, i mean when progress dialog comes then all view/activity behind becomes dim. I am trying to implement option menu of waze gps app (when u press menu button). I have been successful to create animation of that custom menu. But there when that custom view comes from scale animation(0 to 1) then all view in screen except menu is dark. I hope you understand what i am trying to say.

Thanks.

Comment: i can't provide code. Sorry. What i want is to keep one view in focus and all other things in screen to be low brightness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a parent view having less background alpha(set background color as 0xF0000000) and add the view that u want to highlight in the middle of the parent view, now add this parent view to the top of all your other views such a way that the parent view fit your entire screen
**this is a simple implementation remaining is all up to you thanks**